# node.js, setTimeout callback method and "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, callback

I am trying to write a simple polling application using NodeJS. I'm wanting to write an `EventEmitter` that performs an action on a timer and emits events based on the result of that periodic action.

I'm starting by creating my own object and inheriting from `EventEmitter`. I kick off a timer using `setInterval`, and specify the method to call after the timer elapses. Within the timer callback method, I want to reference a variable of the object that I've created, but `this` does not appear to refer to the object.

How can I reference my variable in this method? Here is my code:

```
var util = require('util'),
    events = require('events'),
    timers = require('timers'),
    redis = require('redis');

// define worker object
var JobPoller = function () {
    // inherit event emitter
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);

    // save reference to database
    this.db = redis.createClient();

    // start main loop
    this.interval_id = timers.setTimeout(this.check, 1000);
};

JobPoller.prototype.check = function () {
    // pop a job off the queue if possible
    this.db.rpop('pdf-job-queue', function (err, result) {  
        if (err != null)
            this.emit('error', err);

        if (result != null)
            this.emit('job', JSON.parse(result));

        // check for more jobs
        this.interval_id = timers.setTimeout(this.check, 1000);
    });
};

// inherit from event emitter
util.inherits(JobPoller, events.EventEmitter);

// export the poller instance
module.exports = new JobPoller;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`this.check` is just a simple function, the value of `this` inside that function will be determined when the function is called.

Node should support [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) so you can bind the function to your desired `this` like this:

```
this.interval_id = timers.setTimeout(this.check.bind(this), 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can use a closure to manually force `this` to be what you want:

```
var self = this;
this.interval_id = timers.setTimeout(function() { self.check() }, 1000);
```